# how to extract array elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, frontend

Please help me know how to extract each array element seperated by comma in below example:

```
 array = [37.421998333333335: -122.08400000000002, 35.71529801212532: 51.39060813566725]
```

I tried slice and it does not work for above case. please help me know what's the solution. Finally I would like to extract each element as an object like below:

```
  {'37.421998333333335': -122.08400000000002}
```

Comment: What you posted is not valid JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript is invalid. It needs to be an object or an array, not a combination of both.

#### If you have an object

```js
const
  coords = { 37.421998333333335: -122.08400000000002, 35.71529801212532: 51.39060813566725 },
  pairs = Object.entries(coords).map(entry => Object.fromEntries([entry]));

console.log(pairs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

#### If you have an array

```js
const
  coords = [ 37.421998333333335, -122.08400000000002, 35.71529801212532, 51.39060813566725 ],
  pairs = new Array(coords.length / 2).fill(0)
    .reduce((r, e, i, a) => [...r, [ coords[i * 2], coords[i * 2 + 1] ]], [])
    .map(entry => Object.fromEntries([entry]));

console.log(pairs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```